# REST service cache strategy with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, caching

I have an AngularJS application and I want to cache the REST service responses. I found some libraries like [angular-cached-resource](https://github.com/goodeggs/angular-cached-resource) which can do this by storing the data into the local storage of the web browser.

But sometimes I do some POST / PUT / DELETE REST calls and then some of the REST previously cached service responses need to be performed again. So it seems that it is possible to delete the cached responses then and the call will be sent to the server next time.

But what about if the server sends me in `HTTP Header` some values like the `expires` or the `etag`? I have to read the HTTP Header and react by myself or is there a library in AngularJS which can also handle this?

So if I should hit the server and not read the cache of the local storage is dependent on the HTTP Header Cache fields and if there are any PUT / POST / DELETE calls which have the response that for example "reload of every user settings element" are needed. So I have to take this response and create a map which tells me that for example REST services A, C and F (user settings related stuff) needs to hit the server again next time when they are executed or if the Cache expires from the HTTP Headers.

Is this possible with an AngularJS library or do you have any other recommendations? I think this is similar to Observer or PubSub Pattern, isn't it?

**One more thing**: Is it also possible to have something like PubSub without using a cache / local storage (so also no HTTP Header Cache controls)? So I can not call the REST service, because then it would hit the server, which I do not want in some circumstances (response from a previous REST call which returns me the event "reload of every user settings element").

Comment: You could do it with a pub/sub pattern. Fire an event with the response comes back from a post/put/del request, and have listeners in the services wait for them then do GET request.

Comment: Yes, but maybe I do not need to do the REST call immediately, because the page element which needs to be reload is not visible / on the same web page.

Comment: The way we do it is to listen to an event in the service, like userOptionsService, and when a POST is sent, do a reload in userOptionsService, then in the controller load the data that is stored in userOptionsService.userOptions

Comment: Its not terribly clean, but it works. IF you come up with a different method let me know!

Comment: Do you use a JavaScript library or is it done by yourself? But you do a REST call which is maybe not necessary for the current web page?

Comment: WE do it all ourselves, not sure if there is a library out there for this. If you find one, lemme know

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
app.factory('requestService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var data = {};

    var service = {
        getCall : funtion(requstUrl, successCallback, failureCallback, getFromCache){
                    if(!getFromCache){
                        $http.get(requstUrl)
                            .success(function(data){
                                successCallback(data);
                                data.requstUrl = data;
                            })
                            .error(function(){
                                failureCallback(data);
                            })
                    }else{
                        successCallback(data.requstUrl);
                    }
                },
        postCall : function(requestUrl, paramToPass, successCallback, failureCallback, getFromCache){
                    if(!getFromCache){
                        $http.post(requestUrl, paramToPass)
                             .success(function(data){
                                successCallback(data);
                                data.requstUrl = data;
                             })
                             .error(function(data){
                                failureCallback(data);
                             })
                    }else{
                        successCallback(data.requstUrl);
                    }
        }
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

This is just a simple code I wrote to implement your concept. I haven't tested it and is all yours.